# javascript code with ajax loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I try to add css class with js to element.
I'm trying to add a CSS class to an HTML element via Javascript.

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.delete').addClass('icon-trash');

    });
})(jQuery.noConflict());
```

But when this element is loaded with ajax I need to refresh the page to see it.
How can i fix it ?

Comment: Add the code of adding class after ajax success too

Comment: Add HTML with how ajax is called

Comment: We're trying to help you here, add the code

Comment: why you down my rep ?

Comment: @Brigadier How can you say that _I_ downvoted, Yes, I've down voted on this question after your first comment when I asked to add complete code. And you see your question is having -3 votes which means 2 other users fell the same way I do, the question is not clear and it should add complete code. And if you notice my first comment, that should've solved the problem

Comment: @Brigadier, FYI, I was one of the other 2 users who down-voted your question because It lacks a good question criteria. When I saw your _**harsh comment**_, I wanted to keep track of this, and where it would lead. Tushar's first comment was the first thing you should have tried, and it would definitely have worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code `$('.delete').addClass('icon-trash')` on ajax success callback as below:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data){
          // if you want to play with response, data is what you want
          // Add trash icon to every .delete element in document
          $('.delete').addClass('icon-trash');
    }
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not used ajax in this, You have just used jquery.Read about [Ajax Call](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/) and than use it.
If you want to go with this same code of yours than try to call this function `onload`

like    `<body onload="myFunction()">`

Comment: use  <body onload="myFunction()"> 
This will load your function on page load . Than you can do whatever in your function

Comment: Two things, 1. Why would you bind `onload` even on `body` tag when you can use `$(window).load()`? It's personal preference, but I strongly recommend keeping `HTML` element clean from binding attributes. You have JavaScript to do that for you. 2. You could have edited your first answer instead of adding another.